# Relation on single table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm designing db for auto parts. I need to create a structure where will be groups, sub-groups and auto parts. Each part will belong to one sub-group, but the sub-group could have parent sub-group. This parent sub-group could belong to higher level sub-group. In the end there will be just group - the root. So it's a classic tree. The problem is that there is no fixed number of groups. Sometimes it can be Group -> Sub-Group -> Auto Part, 
sometimes it can be Group -> Sub-Group -> Sub-Group -> Sub-Group -> Auto Part.

Now i have three tables: Groups, SubGroups, AutoParts. 
How i should design relation between subgroups? 
Is it a good idea to make a foreign key called parent sub-group in the SubGroups table that will reference to the other row in the same table? In case when there is only Group in the upper level this property will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do all this in 2 tables  .... on first table just insert all the groups (parent)

Now in other table .. insert all sub-sub- nth sub groups and all nth number of sub groups ... Now in this table you add a field with name (say **reports_to**) **which will contain the next sub-group ID**.
you can now check so and so subgroups reports to which sub-group id ... that will be its sub sub group ... and so on you can continue.
when there is **NO** value in **reports_to** *field*  to a sub-group than that means that is the last nth sub-group of that group.

I hope you you understood ,, this will work perfectly .\
Please mark it as answer if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is one thing that i am worried about. When inserting new sub-group in the application, i will don't have yet its sub sub groups. What if i apply this solution in reverse? I mean, that reports_to field will be an id of higher level sub-group, and when this field will be empty, than the sub-group will have only one parent - main group.

Comment: yes i meant that only .... you have to give id of the upper groupd id ,,,to which it will report.

Comment: suppose i am adding a sub sub group in dat table ,,its respective report_to id will contain its sub -group id (means its parent (say xyz )group id).... and this parent  id (xyz) will contain main parent id in reports_to field